# react-hook-form material ui file upload not giving FileList

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, yup, react-hook-form

i have an issue with react hook form and material-ui file uploading when submiting the form i got  string path of one file instead of FileList
instance

```
        <Controller
          name='attachments'
          control={control}
          defaultValue=''
          render={({ field }) => <input {...field} type='file' multiple />}
        />
```

full code on codesanbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-bhaskara-9vo13?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For it to work, you will have to implement your own `onChange` property. You can use the `field.onChange` callback for this purpose and pass it the file list as an argument. Here's how it can be done:

```js
<Controller
  name="attachments"
  control={control}
  defaultValue=""
  render={({ field }) => (
    <input
      type="file"
      onChange={e => {
        field.onChange(e.target.files);
      }}
      multiple
    />
  )}
/>
```

[Here is the link to the forked source code](https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-snowflake-mitkw?file=/src/Form.js)